# Integer caching for numbers greater than 256 and less than -5

Tags: python, caching

I know that python has a concept of small integers which are numbers from `-5` to `256`, and if two variables assign to same numbers between this range, they both will use the same underlying object.

**From Python documentation,**

```
#ifndef NSMALLPOSINTS
#define NSMALLPOSINTS           257
#endif
#ifndef NSMALLNEGINTS
#define NSMALLNEGINTS           5
#endif
```

> /* Small integers are preallocated in this array so that they    can
>   be shared.    The integers that are preallocated are those in the
>   range    -NSMALLNEGINTS (inclusive) to NSMALLPOSINTS (not inclusive).
>   */

Also [explained here,](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html)

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all
>   integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you
>   actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it
>   should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour
>   of Python in this case is undefined. :-)

Example,

```
a = 255
b = 255
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

gives the same id,

```
1561854394096
1561854394096
```

Which makes sense and also explained on this answer, ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

If two numbers are less than `-5`, they should also have different IDs as follows,

```
a = -6
b = -6
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

gives,

```
2827426032208
2827426032272
```

this makes sense so far,

But any number greater than `256` should have different `id`,

This should return different IDs,

```
a = 257
b = 257
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

But it doesn't

```
2177675280112
2177675280112
```

Even when I am using very large integer, the IDs are same,

```
a = 2571299123876321621378
b = 2571299123876321621378
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

gives me,

```
1956826139184
1956826139184
```

Can someone tell me why number greater than 256 have same IDs even though in the Python code the range is `-5` to `257` (not inclusive)

**EDIT:**

I have tried using PyCharm with both Python 2.7 and 3.6. Also tried on PythonTutor.com

Comment: From a logical point of view, the information that numbers between -5 and 256 have the same ids don't tell you anything about the ids of integers outside of this range.

Comment: it used to, if you check answers on this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers any number greater than `256` used to had different `id`

Comment: @EricDuminil, does that mean python now cache every possible integer `>= -5`

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Python 3.6.3 (I get different ids on the last two examples). Same for Python2. Are you sure this is exactly how you are testing this?

Comment: I ran it on PyCharm using Python 3.6, also tested it on http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: I think those are running wrapping the runs in a function. I suggest you add this information to the question.

Comment: added the details @kabanus

Comment: If you are putting them in a function, the bytecode compiler is probably noticing that the two constants are the same and allocating just one of them. This does not work for `-6` because that's `-` applied to integer `6` at run-time.

Comment: @torek, Thank you for your comment. I haven't put it in any function. just running directly in pycharm. how can I verify how pycharm is causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Also, I tested using `dis.dis` on a definition that sets a variable to `-5` and it loads `-5` as a constant, rather than loading `5` and invoking `-` on it, so that theory seems wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is duplicated, answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347581/why-does-the-is-operator-behave-differently-in-a-script-vs-the-repl)

> When you run code in a .py script, the entire file is compiled into a code object before executing it. In this case, CPython is able to make certain optimizations